# Regex splitting with multiple end brackets

Tags: python, list

I have an input of `10+sqrt(10+(100*20)+20)+sqrt(5)` which I need to be able to split up into `sqrt(...)` as many times as `sqrt` appears (in this instance, twice). The problem I am having is trying to split this up, I have tried on my own and come up with this `(sqrt\()(?<=sqrt\()(.+?)(\)+)` but regex only registers the first `)` it comes across whereas I need it to find the closing bracket.

[image: My REGEX attempt]

As you can see in the picture the orange marker only covers up to the first bracket but i need it to end at the `+20`.

The desired output is a list as follows:

`['10+', 'sqrt(', '10+(100*20)+20', ')', '+', 'sqrt(', '5', ')']`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is regex really the perfect tool to achieve this?

Comment: What would need to happen when you have `sqrt(5+sqrt(4*sqrt(1)+2)+3)`?

Comment: Second @cincout's comment. This is a parsing problem, not a regex problem.

Comment: @trincot the desired output would be `['sqrt(5+sqrt(4*sqrt(1)+2)+3)']` as I'm using functions so it will separate that when running

Comment: @Hunter I noticed my answer did not match your desired output. For a two steps working solution with [PyPI regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) see [this Python demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##RY7dasMwDIXv/RSCXdhKhkkydjMYeZCmNV6qtilN7MluSZ8@U0JhF/rhSJzvxGe@hOljWYYxBs7AdKYZfJJFqQTfoOuqTL@cjUypqmgqLNfaxE/USr1BbWGYrtRnSGEk6C@efZ@JwYsSb0OGGIYpJyB7tnCfjsSpD4JgWhlMNt1/DOvNszPGtF@7A5p9YdoaWyxK7BD1O7B224vrGodOhIQrvrEviuD@zcFPR7Eew2Ndn0BjzNJvNJJEeaF3M5wCwyz55TfZzcdopxGGE8x7pSJLciM3hGX5Aw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the [ast module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#module-ast) from the standard library.
I'm assuming the expression is valid Python.

```py
# Import parser from Python standard library
import ast

# I have an expression to process
expression = '10+sqrt(10+(100*20)+20)+sqrt(5)'

# Parse it
tree = ast.parse(expression)

# Walk the parse tree
for node in ast.walk(tree):
    # Are we a function call?
    if isinstance(node, ast.Call):
        func = node.func
        # Are we a call to 'sqrt'?
        if expression[func.col_offset:func.end_col_offset] == 'sqrt':
            # We have what we want
            start = node.col_offset
            end = node.end_col_offset
            print(expression[start:end], start, end)
```

This outputs...

```py
sqrt(5) 24 31
sqrt(10+(100*20)+20) 3 23
```

Comment: Works exactly as intended, thanks.